# Can't index multiple elements in list of lists in Python (using the : operator)

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix, indexing

I found it strange that indexing using range(:) operator for list of lists is not supported.

Sometimes this result in strange values :

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
>>> a
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
>>> a[0][1]
2
>>> a[1][1]
4
>>> a[2][1]
6
```

However,

```
>>> a[0:3][1]
[3, 4]
```

I was expecting [2,4,6]. What am I missing here ?

I tried this on Numpy arrays as well.`enter code here`

```
>>> a
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
>>> a[0][1]
2
>>> a[1][1]
4
>>> a[2][1]
6
>>> a[0:3][1]
[3, 4]
```

I know I can use list comprehension, but my question is whether ":" is supported for list of lists?

Comment: Why were you expecting `[2,4,6]`?

Comment: You have to use a list comprehension.  Look again at `a[1]` and `a[0:3]`, with a a focus on their nesting.  Each indexing [] operation is applied independently, one after the other.  `numpy` allows you to index all levels with one operation, `a[0:3, 1]`

Answer (score 3):

numpy arrays do support slicing, but you're not considering the shape of the array. In numpy, this array has shape:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]])
print(a.shape)
>>>(4, 2)
```

meaning it's 4x2. If you slice [0:3] you're returning the first three elements of the 1st dimension. i.e.:

```
print(a[0:3])
>>>[[1 2]
    [3 4]
    [5 6]]
```

this output has shape:

```
print(a[0:3].shape)
>>>(3, 2)
```

if you do:

```
print(a[0:3][1])
>>>[3 4]
```

You are again calling the first element of the first dimension of the array that has shape (3, 2).

Instead you want to call:

```
print(a[0:3][:,1])
>>>[2 4 6]
```

Which gives you all of the row elements (i.e. all three elements of the first dimension) at column index 1 (where 0 and 1 represent the indexes for the two dimensions of the second dimension).

even cleaner (recommended):

```
print(a[0:3, 1])
>>>[2 4 6]
```

Comment: For the array, I recommend `a[0:3, 1]` syntax.

Comment: @hpaulj edited and added that to my answer, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using : is totally supported.  Explained below...

So we start with:

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

You asked about:

```
a[0:3][1]
```

We want the items from list a, from positions zero to three [0:3].  Those items returned are

```
[1, 2] --- position 0
[3, 4] --- position 1
[5, 6] --- position 2
[7, 8] --- position 3
```

Then we request from that list the item in position [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WauVh.png), which returns:

```
[3, 4]
```

If you want to access items inside that smaller list you need to add another index, like this:

```
a[0:3][1][1]
```

would return:

```
4
```

Diagram of basic string splitting:
[image: Breakdown of basic splitting]

Your first bracket (represented in blue) is saying "give me elements in list a between positions 0 and 3, which in this case, is ALL of them.

Your second bracket (represented in red) is saying "of the results of my first bracket, give me the element that is in position 1", which is the entire sub-list [3,4]

In this specific case

```
a[0:3][1]
```

could have simply been written as

```
a[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

let us assume a list of list

```
list=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
```

then,

```
list[0:3]
```

will return a list with elements(which are also list) from index 0 to 2

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

so according list[0:3][1] will return the second element([3,4]) whose index is "1" .

> a[0:3][1] will not return[2,4,6] , it returns the list of list with 3 element and chooses the second element.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `a[0:3]` the result of that is a list with the first three elements of `a`. You then call `a[0:3][1]` which returns the 2nd element of that list which is the list `[3,4]`.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinary Python lists do not support this kind of slicing.

You can get `[2, 4, 6]` with Numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]])
>>> a[0:3, 1]
array([2, 4, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]

a[0:3]
```

#### the output of this is a list:

```
>>> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Therefore:

```
a[0:3][1]
```

- Accesses the element at index `1`, which is `[3, 4]`

#### To get the desired output from your list, use `list comprehension`:

```
[x[1] for x in a[0:3]]

>>> [2, 4, 6]
```